# On enter key move to next cell down in a table

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create a form where, if you press enter key on the serial column, the cell below becomes selected. Can someone please solve the correct jquery formula for this task?

I am trying

```
$('.serial').keypress(function(e) {
    console.log(this);
    if (e.which == 13) {
        $(this).nextAll('#serial').first().focus();
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tYFcH/4/

Comment: `'#serial' !== '.serial'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('.serial').keypress(function(e) {
    console.log(this);
    if (e.which == 13) {
        $(this).closest('tr').next().find('input.serial').focus();
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tYFcH/6/

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you want to move to the cell below when hitting enter in *any* input, use this:

```
$('table input').keypress(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        var $this = $(this),
            index = $this.closest('td').index();

        $this.closest('tr').next().find('td').eq(index).find('input').focus();
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Here's your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tYFcH/13/

Comment: Is it possible for loop?

Answer (score 0):

The next-in-dom plugin was written for this purpose. *Disclaimer: I wrote it*

http://techfoobar.com/jquery-next-in-dom/

```
$('.serial').keypress(function(e) {
    if (e.which == 13) {
        $(this).nextInDOM('.serial').focus();
    }
});
```