# JQuery HTML Traverse Table Input Cells Vertically

Tags: jquery, focus, html-table, keyup

I have a table with four columns.

I want a user to capture values in all input cells in ANY single column.

==> symbolizes ENTER keypress
Example: If a user decides to capture values in Day02 column only, the table traversal should be :
124==>127==>130==>134

If a user decides to capture values in Day03 column only, the table traversal should be :
126==>129==>130==>131

Can some write the quote using jquery, the keyup event handler and the focus() method.

Thank you in advance

```
<table border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="keytable" style="width: 500px;">
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <th id="headcol">Data Element</th>
        <th>Day01</th>
        <th>Day02</th>
        <th>Day03</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="headcol"><strong>medical dose A</strong></td>
        <td id="actdata"><input id="124"/></td>
        <td id="actdata"><input id="125"/></td>
        <td id="actdata"><input id="126"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="headcol"><strong>medical dose B</strong></td>
        <td id="actdata"><input id="127"/></td>
        <td id="actdata"><input id="128"/></td>
        <td id="actdata"><input id="129"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="headcol"><strong>medical dose C</strong></td>
        <td id="actdata"><input id="130"/></td>
        <td id="actdata"><input id="131"/></td>
        <td id="actdata"><input id="132"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="headcol"><strong>medical dose D</strong></td>
        <td id="actdata"><input id="133"/></td>
        <td id="actdata"><input id="134"/></td>
        <td id="actdata"><input id="135"/></td>
    </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: This isn't a place to ask people to write code for you.

Comment: First important thing - you can't have multiple id's on page, use classes. Also, if you can change HTML, then you could make traversing much easier...

Answer (score 1):

I can't write code for you. But I can give suggestion to a possible solution.
You can keep a different class on each column.

e.g.

```
   <tr>
       <td class="c1"></td>
       <td class="c2"></td>
       <td class="c3"></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td class="c1"></td>
       <td class="c2"></td>
       <td class="c3"></td>
     </tr>
```

Then use the class name of column you want to get the column values.

e.g. for first column

```
var firstColumnItems = document.getElementsByClassName("c1");
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your contribution @nevermind. The following code  from [On enter key move to next cell down in a table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14470963/on-enter-key-move-to-next-cell-down-in-a-table) has partially resolved my problem.

The code is

```
var inputs = $("#keytable :input");
inputs.on("keypress keyup",function(e) { 
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        var $this = $(this),
            index = $this.closest('td').index();

        $this.closest('tr').next().find('td').eq(index).find('input').focus();
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
    }
});
```

However,  in the core of this application there is another keypress/keyup event which is firing after adding my own keypress/key. This former keypress/keyup moves the cursor to the next cell in the same row and the latter moves the mouse cursor to the next cell in the same column just as I want. Is there a possible way to suppress/prevent the former from firing on my keytable object without deleting this former code?